# How to make Python's print() non-blocking?

Tags: python, terminal

I am running a Python script on a Rasberry Pi which appears to freeze intermittently on the `print()` call. The script only freezes occasionally and continues when someone focuses on the terminal and presses the "enter" button or hits ctrl+c.

My guess is that the problem here is that the `print()` call is waiting to get some kind of response back from the terminal which it doesn't get when the user does something unexpected, such as highlight text, right-click drag, or some other thing (which I am unable to replicate). To be clear, the script hangs indefinitely in this case, and not for the 120 seconds specified in the time.sleep() call directly below.

My question is this: *is there any print call I can use in python which doesn't wait to get a response back from the console so that it doesn't freeze in unknown cases like the above?*

I've put my code below, although the specifics of what it does are not particularly relevant to the question.

```
while True:
    directory_pump_files =  glob.glob("./pumplog*.csv") #read in some files from the file system

    for file_path in directory_pump_files:
        try_upload_file(file_path, pump_files_done, "/batchUpload/create") #upload the pump file

        
    directory_log_files =  glob.glob("./log*.csv")

    for file_path in directory_log_files:
        try_upload_file(file_path, log_files_done, "/batchUpload/SensorReadings") #upload the log file
    print ("sleep")
    time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: The `print` call is followed by a `time.sleep`. Isn't the sleep that's causing your program to pause and "freeze" for a while?

Comment: The program hangs indefinitely, not just for the 120 seconds specified in time.sleep
Cheers for clarifying this - I have edited the question to be more understandable

Comment: See [How to flush output of print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230751/2745495)

Comment: What is consuming stdout? When it hangs indefinitely, has 'sleep' been output? Sounds like buffering - if the output buffer gets full, writing to that buffer gets blocked. Presumably the consumer of the buffer isn't emptying it. Consider making the buffer (a lot) larger - but if the consumer is really sluggish, that will only postpone the situation where the buffer is full, i.e. `print()` will still block. The real problem is the consumer of the buffer.

Comment: The consumer is just the standard rasberry pi terminal program LXTerminal 0.3.2

Comment: When it hangs indefinitely, has 'sleep' been output?

Comment: Indeed it does, although the nature of the loop is that it outputs "sleep" every two minutes and gets a new file from the filesystem every hour.
So all I see in the terminal is a notification that the file has uploaded, and then a bunch of sleep statements, and then a hang.
So I don't have proof of which statement it's breaking on, as all I can see from the terminal is a bunch of lines saying "sleep." I am just inferring that this is a terminal issue, as ctrl+c seems to clear the script to keep running.
https://imgur.com/a/a3JeXOz

Answer (score 2):

It might be an issue with the terminal's buffering mechanism. Normally, the buffer is flushed when a newline is encountered, but things could work differently on a Raspberry Pi.

You can try to use the `flush` argument. From `help(print)`:

> ```
> print(...)
>     print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>     
>     Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
>     Optional keyword arguments:
>     file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
>     sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
>     end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
>     flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
> ```

By using `print("sleep", flush=True)` the string will be printed immediately.